# SuiteScript custom segment Permissions

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am working SS2, and I am attempting to access a column on a record that is a custom segment, I need to get the text value of the field. I am getting the following error. "Permission Violation: You need a higher permission for value management of custom segment" I have not seen this before. Is there a specific permission that I need to access this from a script? The code is running in a restlet that is accepting data from the outside, taking in updates and sending it back out to the caller.

Any help would be great
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Permission Violation" error basically occurs because of the role you re using while authenticating the Restlet doesn't have rights to access that record.
To Resolve this issue, assign rights to the role you re using. You don't have to change anything in the Script

Comment: That worked awesome thank you, one thing though when I try to access the 'name' value using searchRec.getValue({fieldId:'name'}); it errors out telling me I am missing a field. Is it not the same syntax as other records?  Here is the error ""type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"Result.getValue: Missing a required argument: name" Thanks for all your help.